# How to avoid compilation error 'std::system_error' in simple c++ program using thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, runtime-error, codeblocks

I'm testing a simple C++ thread program in Code::Block IDE

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void thread_function()
{
    std::cout<<"Function1 thread is running\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(thread_function);
    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

and it give following run-time error

```
terminate called after throwing as instance of 'std::system_error' 
  what(): Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted
Aborted(core dumped)
```

but when i manually compile the code using

```
g++ -std=c++11 -pthread main.cpp
```

it compile and **run** without any errors.
i already change the Code::Block compiler to g++ c++11 but still getting the error.
can anyone tel me how to fix this problem in Code::Block IDE

Comment: What is `std""cout<<"\n";`?

Comment: @NathanOliver I bet he meaned `std::cout<<"\n";` ;)

Comment: @PaoloM not a risky guess, but why not post the *actual* code.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://ideone.com/9Ekrf1) after fixing your typo.

Comment: @Quentin I'll never understand this...

Comment: Line std""cout<<"\n"; was a typing mistake guys

Comment: You have to add -pthread compilation flag to your code::block project settings.

Comment: @dilee why type when you can copy paste =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like when you link your program with Code::Blocks "-pthread" option is not enabled. You need to add it for linker options (note do not add -pthread library but add that as an option).

Comment: can you explain how to do it in code::black and why it necessary to add -pthread

Comment: @dilee how it is explained here http://oghazal.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-ptrhead-on-linux-using.html as why I do not quite understand your question, are you asking why -pthread is ncessesary to build or why it is not there already?

Comment: thank you very much for your help,i have very little knowledge about c++ so pardon me if i ask dumb thing, i asked why we need to add -pthread to build thread enable c++ programs,in java and c# we don't do such thing for threading

Comment: @dilee because C and C++ has this principle: "you do not pay for what you do not use"

Comment: can you tell me how can i add -pthread to the project Linker Settings,do i have to download and install -pthread library to some where?